# Why does my website need "Enable 32-bit applications"?

Tags: .net-4.0, x86, 64-bit, iis-8, corflags

I've just been working on migrating a staging web site from II6 to IIS8.

IIS8 comes with an option **Enable 32-Bit Applications** which is a true false flag. The explanation of this flag is:

> [enable32BitAppOnWin64] If set to True for an application pool on a
>   64-bit operating system, the worker process(es) serving the
>   application pool run in WOW64 (Windows on Windows64) mode. In WOW64
>   mode, 32-bit processes load only 32-bit applications.

Now if I set this to `False` my web site stops serving and I get a 500 logging an error message of:

> ISAPI Filter
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll'
>   could not be loaded due to a configuration problem. The current
>   configuration only supports loading images built for a AMD64 processor
>   architecture. The data field contains the error number. To learn more
>   about this issue, including how to troubleshooting this kind of
>   processor architecture mismatch error, see

Now I guessed that their must be an assembly with x86 flags set, so I followed the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64) using [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check this. But the all return `Any CPU`, i.e.

```
Version    : v4.0.30319
CLR Header : 2.5
PE         : PE32
CorFlags   : 9
ILONLY     : 1
32BIT      : 0
Signed     : 0
```

There are slight veriations but thats the jist.

**So why do I need to set Enable 32-Bit Applications to `True`?**

So I've done some more investigation using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247098/x64-net-compilation-process-explorer-oddity) helped) and it appears that if I set enable 32-bit applications to `False` and even though the Corflags says they do not require 32 bit several of the dlls do have an image type of 32-bit:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've gotten to the bottom of this, eventually!

So it appears that this machine is missing some of the x64 configuration. Particuarly the **"ISAPI Filters"** configuration contained the standard .net 4 `aspnet_filter.dll` (*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll*) but not the x64 version (*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll*)

[image]

From talking with our infrastructuire guys they suggested the best way to get this set up correctly is to *"uninstall the .Net 4.0 feature and re-install it"* bear in mind this requires a reboot!